# Weird time-of-day cycle in pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, time-series, plotly

I want to create a scatterplot over multiple days but analyze performance by time-of-day for all days.  The index of my DataFrame is a `RangeIndex`, and I am perplexed by how the time-of-day has multiple cycles rather than a single ramp from earliest time to latest time.  These are trades results, and the cycles seem somehow related to the symbol, but I don't see how that can be.

```
df['time_of_day'] = df['entrydate'].dt.time
df['time_of_day_num'] = df['time_of_day'].apply(lambda x: x.hour * 3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second)

df.sort_values(by='time_of_day_num', inplace=True)

tod = df['time_of_day']
pnl = df["realizedpnl"]

fig = px.scatter(df, x=tod, y=pnl, color='short_symbol', hover_data=['entrydate','realizedpnl'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

What seems to be happening is that IWM covers the first cycle, SPY spans the first and second cycle, and QQQ spans three cycles.  There are very few TSL and XLF, but they seem to be clumped at the end, maybe incorporating a fourth and fifth cycle, though I can't be sure.

I just don't see how the x-axis is doing any of this, based on my code.

**Update**

Here are some charts where I am plotting time_of_day_num on y, in place of realizedpnl.  This makes it clear that there is something funky going on.

In the screenshots below, I enable/disable various symbols, which makes the interaction issues more obvious.

It seems clear that there is a sorting or grouping by short_symbol, based on the way the charts appear.  Is there something wrong in my logic, or is this a Plotly bug?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

I think this can be considered the smoking gun.  Without setting the color to short_symbol, time_of_day_num plots as a monotonically increasing function, as expected.  The color setting seems to be doing something unexpected to the chart.

I believe this is a Plotly bug.  Does anyone disagree?

[image]

Comment: I think that your scatter isn't plotting the `time_of_day` in chronological order – i can see that entries from `09:56:52` and `09:56:48` are on completely different parts of the xaxis – is this behavior intended?

Comment: @DerekO, no, that's my question.  That's what I meant by multiple cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that when you use the argument `color='short_symbol'`, plotly express will plot each portion of the dataframe  separately and as you correctly noted in your question, this will mess up the order of the timestamps on the xaxis. Another [possible] issue is that the format of the x values you are passing are of type `datetime.time`, and this format may not be understood by plotly.

Below I've created a sample dataset that reproduces the behavior you're seeing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools

np.random.seed(42)
t1 = ['2023-01-01 23:23:23', '2023-01-02 23:23:23', '2023-01-01 11:11:11', '2023-01-02 09:09:09']
t2 = ['2023-01-01 09:09:09', '2023-01-02 23:23:23', '2023-01-01 10:10:10', '2023-01-01 18:18:18']
t3 = ['2023-01-02 09:09:09', '2023-01-02 23:23:23', '2023-01-02 10:10:10', '2023-01-02 18:18:18']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'entrydate': t1+t2+t3,
    'realizedpnl': np.random.uniform(-1000,2000,size=12),
    'short_symbol': ['a']*4 + ['b']*4 + ['c']*4
})

df['entrydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entrydate'])

df['time_of_day'] = df['entrydate'].dt.time
df['time_of_day_num'] = df['time_of_day'].apply(lambda x: x.hour * 3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second)

df.sort_values(by='time_of_day_num', inplace=True)
```

---

`df` looks like the following:

```
             entrydate  realizedpnl short_symbol time_of_day  time_of_day_num
3  2023-01-02 09:09:09   795.975453            a    09:09:09            32949
4  2023-01-01 09:09:09  -531.944079            b    09:09:09            32949
8  2023-01-02 09:09:09   803.345035            c    09:09:09            32949
6  2023-01-01 10:10:10  -825.749163            b    10:10:10            36610
10 2023-01-02 10:10:10  -938.246517            c    10:10:10            36610
2  2023-01-01 11:11:11  1195.981825            a    11:11:11            40271
7  2023-01-01 18:18:18  1598.528437            b    18:18:18            65898
11 2023-01-02 18:18:18  1909.729556            c    18:18:18            65898
0  2023-01-01 23:23:23   123.620357            a    23:23:23            84203
1  2023-01-02 23:23:23  1852.142919            a    23:23:23            84203
5  2023-01-02 23:23:23  -532.016439            b    23:23:23            84203
9  2023-01-02 23:23:23  1124.217733            c    23:23:23            84203
```

---

Then we call `px.scatter` with argument `color='short_symbol'`:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='time_of_day', y='realizedpnl', color='short_symbol', hover_data=['entrydate','realizedpnl'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

I would guess that plotly [correctly] places down markers for `short_symbol = 'a'`, but then doesn't "know" where to place down the other markers for short_symbols `'b'` and `'c'` relative to datetime.time markers for `'a'` on the xaxis.

One possible solution to preserve the order of the xaxis ticks would be to instead plot the `x='time_of_day_num'` with `y='realizedpnl'`, then [overwrite the tickmarks](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array) by supplying the `time_of_day` values as an array of strings.

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='time_of_day_num', y='realizedpnl', color='short_symbol', hover_data=['entrydate','realizedpnl'])
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df['time_of_day_num'].values,
        ticktext = [str(ts) for ts in df['time_of_day'].values]
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea.  Unfortunately, I have far too many rows in my DataFrame to make that relabelling practical.  Jupyter hangs when I try.  Is there a way to fill the tickvals and ticktext only with the xaxis ticks, rather than every point in the xaxis?  Is there a way to retrieve the current tick labels and reformat them?

Comment: it might be possible – let me see what I can come up with